# Flutter ThemeExtension: What to to if lerp is not support by property

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I am Trying to work with flutter [ThemeExtension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/extensions.html) and I don't have quit understood how `lerp` works.

Here a example ThemeExtension:

```
enum MyButtonVariant {
  solid,
  soft,
  outlined,
  text,
}

class MyButtonStyle extends ThemeExtension<MyButtonStyle> {
  const MyButtonStyle({
    this.variant,
    this.margin,
  });

  final ButtonVariant? variant;
  final EdgeInsets? margin;

  @override
  ThemeExtension<MyButtonStyle> copyWith({
    MyButtonVariant? variant,
    EdgeInsets? margin,
  }) =>
      MyButtonStyle(
        variant: variant ?? this.variant,
        margin: margin ?? this.margin,
      );

  @override
  ThemeExtension<MyButtonStyle> lerp(
      ThemeExtension<MyButtonStyle>? other, double t) {
    if (other is! MyButtonStyle) {
      return this;
    }

    return MyButtonStyle(
      variant: WHAT SHOULD BE HERE? ,
      margin: EdgeInsets.lerp(margin, other.margin, t),
    );
  }
}
```

What should be used in the `lerp` function for `variant`?

I was thinking that something like this could work:

```
 variant: t < 0.5 ? variant : other.variant,
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to include all of your properties in the `lerp` method of your theme extension. The only drawback is that those properties will instantly change from one value to another rather than smoothly interpolating between them. That might not be a problem. Maybe that widget is unlikely to be on screen when the theme changes, or maybe so many other things are smoothly changing all over the screen that most users won't notice one little thing changing instantly.

For your situation in particular, however, I think you could try using a `ButtonStyle` in your theme extension which does come with its own `lerp` method. Interpolating between enum values won't ever work, because they are discrete values. Nothing exists between `MyButtonVariant.solid` and `MyButtonVariant.soft`.